# Opening file association starts ClickOnce application with blank command line

Tags: vb.net, command-line, registry, clickonce, file-association

**I'm developing a VB.NET Windows Forms app to edit files of with extension `*.fltp`, and I want to use ClickOnce deployment.  But the File Association part of my manifests doesn't seem to work.**

From my time programming in C++, my understanding is that double-clicking a file in Windows Explorer causes Windows to undertake the following actions:

1. Scan the registry for the file extension (say, `*.doc`)
2. Discover in the registry that the file extension is registered to a command-line scheme (in this case, `winword.exe %1`)
3. Run that command-line (i.e. `winword.exe "Untitled.doc"`).

Now, ClickOnce doesn't offer such fine-grained control; in MSVS, I just go to the Publication options and get to associate my app with `*.fltp`.  I assumed it follows the general pattern of putting `App.exe %1` in the registry, and wrote my application to that spec.

When I deploy the application, it seems as though the application is registered to `*.fltp` files: their icon and description changes, and double-clicking on them in Windows Explorer opens the app.

But the command line is blank, so my app just opens a blank new document!  When I place in one of my files

```
Private Sub Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox(Command)
End Sub
```

the deployed app just shows an empty messagebox.  (The same behavior shows if I use `System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox.Show`, `System.Environment.GetCommandLine`, or `My.Application.CommandLineArgs` — it's not the legacy VB functions that are at fault.)

The registry entries are similar to those for a C++ app, but not identical, so I can't figure out what they do.

**How can I tell which file the user double-clicked on?**

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly deduced that ClickOnce doesn't pass the file as a command-line argument.

The problem here is that ClickOnce (typically) checks for app updates right when the app starts.  So if ClickOnce used the fixed registry schema you describe for C++ apps, Windows might start the app with a file location on the command line, ClickOnce realize it needs to update the app, quick download the new executable and update the registry, and start the updated executable in a new process, accidentally squashing the command-line along the way.  So it stashes the file in an `Appdomain`, does any update stuff necessary, and then starts the app in the child `Appdomain`.

**TL;DR: You want `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData` instead of the command line.**